# Should this Debug code be used in a VBA object loop?

Tags: oop, vba, excel

Looking to include the below code as an instance of a loop through a **Set**
 range object including multiple cell values. This link provides a good overview of **Debug.Print** but the workings of **.Address** remain a mystery to me.

```
        Debug.Print .Address
```

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Address must be related to a cell or range like this:

```
Debug.Print Range("A1").Address
```

Or if your using a with statement like this:

```
With Range("A1")
 Debug.Print .Address
End With
```

The output is printed to your vba immediate window and looks like this:

```
$A$1
```

[image]

---

You could also write it to other locations like this:

```
MsgBox (Range("A1").Address)

Range("B1").Value = Range("A1").Address
```

Comment: It would be in a **With** loop.

Comment: **With** is technically not a loop.  It's just a way to access  multiple properties without having to write more code.  Either way, it's printing out the address of the cell to your immediate window.

Comment: @BobHopez `With` is not a loop. It just stores a copy of an object and lets you call methods of that object without giving a variable name. So `With Range("A1"): Debug.Print .Address: End With` is the same as `Dim r As Range: Set r = Range("A1"): Debug.Print r.Address: Set r = Nothing`.

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained :)

Comment: I understand that **.Address** will print the cell reference--e.g., "A1", but where to? It's not a function to be calculated within a cell.

Comment: Bob - See edit with a little more info on where it goes and how else you can use it.

Comment: **MsgBox** seems like a more appropriate alt to **debug.print**, as the Immediate Window doesn't 'clear' after the command. Appreciated!

Comment: @PortlandRunner note: with a **Set** object range, the message option will work with `Msgbox exampleRangeObject.Address`,but not with `Msgbox Range(exampleRangeObject).Address` as it does with a Range("A1") ref.